# mysql query to select all rows of current month?

Tags: mysql

I have a columns name startdate which is of datetime type.And i have to fetch all rows  between start date and end date of a current month.Which is from 1/nov/2014 to 30/Nov/2014.

Answer (score 14):

```
select * from your_table
where year(curdate()) = year(startdate)
and month(curdate()) = month(startdate)
```

Answer (score 5):

To find out all the records of current month is done with this simple one line code:

```
SELECT * FROM `Your_Table` WHERE MONTH(startdate) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

Comment: That query would show records from other years, thus not being from the current month.

Comment: Yes add `AND YEAR(startdate) = YEAR(CURDATE())`

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is to do all the date arithmetic on the current date.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.date >= date(now()) - interval day(date(now()) + 1 day and
      t.date < (date(now()) - interval day(date(now()) + 1 day) + interval 1 month
```

The complex date arithmetic calculates the first day of this month and the first day of the next month.  This formulation allows MySQL to take advantage of an index on the date column.

Answer (score 0):

To get data between dates:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2014-11-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2014-11-30', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting day or week or month records use this function:

```
 function get_records_by_period($period, $your_date) {
if ($period == 'today') {
    $timeSQL = ' Date($your_date)= CURDATE()';
}
if ($period == 'week') {
    $timeSQL = ' YEARWEEK($your_date)= YEARWEEK(CURDATE())';
}
if ($period == 'month') {
    $timeSQL = ' Year($your_date)=Year(CURDATE()) AND Month(`your_date`)= Month(CURDATE())';
}

$Sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ".$timeSQL
return $Result = $this->db->query($Sql)->result_array();
}
```