# Find the first second timestamp of current month given a day

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, select

I have a date format like `'2016-09-21'`. What I want to achieve is given that day find the first second of the first day of the current month (current year).

I want to do this because a have a MySQL column with a `DATETIME` format. So I want to `SELECT` all records of the current month.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541326/postgresqls-date-trunc-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL to get all records of the current month:

```
select * from your_table
where year(curdate()) = year(datecolumn)
and month(curdate()) = month(datecolumn)
```

From: [mysql query to select all rows of current month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714529/mysql-query-to-select-all-rows-of-current-month)